# How should I store a 3rd party API authentication token in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am looking at using [Savon](http://savonrb.com/) to consume a SOAP API. One of the requirements of this particular API is that an authentication token be supplied in each request to the API. That is, apart from the request that returns the authentication token itself. That call just needs a username and password. The token expires after 20mins of inactivity.

My question is, what is the best practice for storing this token? It's surely not advisable to make two requests every time, one for the token and one for the actual request?

I was considering storing it in a session variable but this would mean generating a new token for each visitor, which I presume is not necessary. However, it would mean I could set a 20 minute expiry on it very easily though.

If I store it in the database, how would I know whether or not it will have expired before making the call to the API, without a lot of extra logic?

Or, should I store it in the database and simply make a background call to the API every few minutes to ensure the token never expires?

Or am I barking up completely the wrong tree?!

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I thought I should update my own question to inform anyone who stumbles across it.

I ended up going with a database storage option. I created an ActiveRecord-less class to manage the API access / login. The class returns an access token. I first check the database to see if there exists a token with updated_at within the last 20 minutes. If so, I return it and 'touch' the record in the database so that the updated_at column is refreshed. If not, I query the API for a new token, update the database and return it. This allows me to reduce queries to the API login function.

Comment: Forgot to say - I'd still appreciate any feedback as to whether or not this is a sensible approach.

Comment: Does the API tell you when a token has expired?  You could watch for that response and at that point request a new one.

As for storing it in the database, the only concern I have is that it has to hit the DB before it can make a API request.  Maybe Redis would be better?  Or memcache?

Comment: Thanks Jason. The API does tell you by way of an error message when you make a request. I was just trying to preempt that scenario. Although a call is made to the database before every request it is a very simple call. There is only ever one token stored in the table, overwritten every time it is reset. I didn't consider that to be too expensive. But, an alternative like redis or memcache would be better I suppose. Let me look into those an get back. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You also need to worry about race conditions if this will be a highly traffic'd site.

Comment: Isn't that another argument for using the database? I can lock the row whilst checking and updating the token? Perhaps it's best to have a background process periodically (every 15 minutes) update the database / memcache / redis?